# Show unit in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, donut-chart

I have a **donut chart** using Google Chart

[image]

---

My downlink value is 514494797.

I want to show the unit next to it. Ex. `514494797` kbps.

How do I achieve that ?

---

**data**

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Bandwith'],
          ['downlink', {{$private['down_bytes']}}], // data from controller
          ['uplink', {{$private['up_bytes']}}] // data from controller
        ]);
```

**options**

```
var options = {
          legend: 'none',
          pieSliceText: 'label',
          title: 'Private',
          colors: ['#77DD77', '#008000'],
          width:'100%',
          height: 300,
          pieHole: 0.4,


        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use [NumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter) function, and specified the `suffix`

**Solution**

```
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
         suffix: 'kbps'
    });

    formatter.format(data, 1);
```

**Result**

[image]